# Find the values of max in another column

Tags: excel

I have two columns, one is for name and another is for points. I have max value from second column, but I need also name which is max value in sheet.

For example I have result of all student only total and student! name I have max total score with function but I need which student reach this value I want that student name from all student. Here I attached image also you can more familiar with my problem.

[need excel formula help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrpF7.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot sort your table, then you will need an array function:

```
=INDEX(A2:A8,MATCH(1,IF(B2:B8=D2,1,0),0))
```

[image]

for the data above. change the range accordingly. After inputting the formula, make sure to use 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> since this is an array formula, instead of pressing only <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing it.